# Windows freeware/opensource video editor

Tags: windows, video, editing

I've googled and googled and googled, but I can't find a decent FREE windows video editor. Does anybody know one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For basic editing there is [Virtualdub](http://www.virtualdub.org/). For effects, I'd go with [ZS4](http://www.zs4.net/download) or [Jahshaka](http://jahshaka.org/) (the latter is my preference).

Comment: It's a bit too basic, sorry.

Comment: I wasn't done :)

Comment: @Joe, the link for Jahshaka is broken. You may have to use **www**.jahshaka.org

Answer (score 2):

[blender](http://blender.org/) is able to load, edit (as in cut and blend different streams, and mix with sound) videos. see [here](http://www.blender.org/features-gallery/features/):

```
Imaging and Compositing

* Complete list of composite node filters, convertors, color and vector 
  operators and mixers including Chroma Key, Blur, RGB Curves, Z Combine,
  Color Ramp, Gamma Correct
* Preview panel to define the portion of interest. A composite then only
  happens on this part
* Near realtime sequencer can edit hours of video
```