# How can I split an mpeg file into multiple pieces in windows

Tags: mpeg

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Split MPEG video from command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/31135/split-mpeg-video-from-command-line)
>   [Windows freeware/opensource video editor.](https://superuser.com/questions/61409/windows-freeware-opensource-video-editor)

I've looked at the other answers, and ffmpeg doesn't help because I need to see the video of where to clip it.

There's a zillion freeware programs that all are happily willing to re-encode the video for you, but it's a streaming protocol. I just want something that will split the file at a frame boundary. I've also found a few freeware tools that do this except they don't actually work when you start pressing the buttons.

How can I see where I am splitting the mpeg file?

Comment: ffmpeg will do the job, duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/31135/split-mpeg-video-from-command-line

Comment: have you been through the other questions here: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-editing ? which programs did you try that "don't actually work"?

Comment: I'm missing the part where ffmpeg lets me scroll through the video and select the frame to split at that way.