# Freeware Video Editor

Tags: windows-8, video, media

I am looking for a video editor that can add images to videos. I was hoping it could make white clear in images that I add to the video, like in paint. I am using Windows 8.
I'm hoping for freeware (meaning free software).
I have a video converter, so any format will work.

Comment: What format video? mpeg,avi, or etc?

Answer (score 1):

If "freeware" requirement is mandatory, you can use either VirtualDub or [AVI Demux](http://avidemux.sf.net/).
In my opinion, paid video editors are much better.

Comment: Fair Warning: VirtualDub is a pain to use and has very limited format support unless you find a bunch of plugins and do a lot of manual work to get them to function properly.

Unless you are going to use Linux paid software is 100x better and easier to use. KDENLIVE and Openshot are great, but linux only. Unless your willing to create a virtual machine within windows.

Answer (score 0):

A user here brought up Blender, and provided some good examples of why to use it.

[Windows freeware/opensource video editor](https://superuser.com/questions/61409/windows-freeware-opensource-video-editor?rq=1)